# Pillow: image.getcolors(maxcolors) returns None unless maxcolors ≥ 148279

Tags: image, image-processing, python-3.6, python-imaging-library

I'm using [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/index.html) to read an image, and get all its colours with `Image.getcolors()`. From the [`getcolors()` reference page](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getcolors):

> `Image.getcolors(maxcolors=256)`
>
> Returns a list of colors used in this image.
>   Parameters:    maxcolors – Maximum number of colors. If this number is exceeded, this method returns None. The default limit is 256
>   colors.
>   Returns:   An unsorted list of (count, pixel) values.

I am using the following code snippet to load an image, [lena.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkyCi.png).

```
from PIL import Image

def main(filename):
    with Image.open(filename) as image:
        colors = image.getcolors(maxcolors) #where maxcolors is some value, as explained below
        print(colors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main("lena.png")
```

This will print `None` if `image.getcolors()` recieves no argument or `maxcolors < 148279`. If `maxcolors >= 148279`, the values are printed as expected. The output is along the lines of `[(1, (233, 130, 132)), (1, (243, 205, 168)),`...`(1, (223, 140, 118))]`, a list of tuples containing the occurence of the colour first, and a tuple of the RGB values second. I checked the output, and there is not one single value greater than `255`.

When using another image, [test.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Rpq6.jpg), the same occurs. There seems to be no correlation to filetype or dimension. Adding `image.load()` above `colors = ...` does not change this either. `148279` is a *prime*, which makes this seem even weirder to me.

## Why does `getcolors()` not work as intended with the default value, and why does it work with `148279`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it works correctly, but is maybe not described very well.

If you use **ImageMagick** on your Lena image, as follows, you will find that your image has exactly 148,279 unique colours in it - [see explanatory link here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php):

```
identify -format %k lena.png
148279
```

So, I think the Pillow description probably means that you want a list of the unique colours, so long as there are fewer than the number you specify. You can change the number of colours, also with **ImageMagick**, to say 32:

```
convert lena.png -colors 32 lena.png
```

Then run your Python again, and you will have to make `maxcolors` 32 or more to get a list of the colours. If you set it to 31 or less, it outputs `None`.

Comment: Thank you, I had misunderstood the specification. I thought "number of colours" would refer to the number of possible values for each channel, like 256 for 8bit RGB.

Comment: WTF... what's the rationale behind this behaviour?!?!? For example: I have to filter "boring" images so I thought: easy. `getcolors(10000)` and see if `len(colors)` is less than 1000, i.e. my image has less than 1000 unique colors, then it's boring otherwise it is not. So do I have to always put a huge number to ensure that a list is returned and then check the size of the list?  What is the meaning of `None`? I thought that by putting `10000` as argument `Image` would stop producing elements after finding 10k elements, i.e. it allowed a lazy evaluation when possible...